# Download file from external url using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, servlets

I want to download the file coming from an external url. But I'm getting errors. Is there any better way to achieve this?

This is my code:

```
public ResponseEntity downloadAsset() throws IOException {

    final String username = "abd";
    final String password = "rewf";
    String url = "https://www.clickdimensions.com/links/TestPDFfile.pdf";

    String plainCreds = username + ":" +  password;
    byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
    byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
    String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        System.out.println("response:: " + response.getEntity());
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentLength(response.getEntity().getContentLength())
                        .body(response.getEntity().getContent());
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

I'm getting below error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No converter found for return value of type: class org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:230)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:226)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this part of code is throwing an exception `.body(response.getEntity().getContent());`. `getContent()` method returns **InputStream** and you cannot just simply but it in response body. You need to properly handle it (see: https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-string or http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/inputstream.html).